# Communicating between 2 python scripts using popen

Tags: python, subprocess, popen

Let's say we got the problem as displayed in the figure.

```
scriptA.py                               scriptB.py

get directory
modify directory
run scriptB with directory as input
                                -------> get directory
                                         open .txt file
                                         scan its contents
                                <------- return content to scriptA
print content
```

My ScriptA example is:

```
import os
import subprocess
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
   directory = os.getcwd() + os.sep + 'some extension'
    
   p = subprocess.Popen("python ScriptB.py", stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
        
   results = p.communicate(input = str.encode(directory))[0]
    
   print(results)
```

But now I'm not sure how to access the input in ScriptB. And what is necessary so `communicate` detects the content which is the output of ScriptB? And is my example correct?

Comment: Why not import the other script as a module, or is that for an exercise?

Comment: I had to do something not too dissimilar recently, was disappointed/frustrated by `subprocess`, and ended up using `pexpect` instead: https://pexpect.readthedocs.io/en/stable/

Answer (score 0):

As noted in comments, a vastly superior solution to what you propose is usually to refactor `scriptB` so that you can `import` it from `scriptA` and just call its functions directly, without requiring a separate subprocess.

If you can't or don't want to do that, the absolutely simplest arrangement is to write `scriptB` so that it accepts a command-line parameter, and prints the result to standard output.

```py
results = subprocess.run(
    ['python', 'scriptB.py', directory],
    check=True, text=True, capture_output=True).stdout
```

Notice the absence of `shell=True`, which adds no value at all here, and the corresponding division of the command line into a list of strings. Perhaps see also [Actual meaning of 'shell=True' in subprocess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3172470/actual-meaning-of-shell-true-in-subprocess)

If you need `scriptB.py` to accept input on standard input (often, a dubious design for many reasons) that's not very different;

```py
result = subprocess.run(
    ['python', 'scriptB.py'],
    input=directory + '\n',
    check=True, text=True, capture_output=True).stdout
```

You really want to avoid `subprocess.Popen()` unless you are in a situation which `subprocess.run()` or its owner siblings cannot handle.